# hierarchical traverse a target object and replace a source obj into it by using its key

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I want to merge two objects:

Target object:

```
"ac0ca677-edb6-4187-85f3-c8b02e874315": {
                "groups": {
                    "30f8168b-0e98-4d1d-b7d9-e652651ad240": {
                        "groups": {
                            "4cab91b5-1732-40c3-81a7-6471da687061": {
                                "name": "Transformer 1.2.3",
                            },
                            "e4e4c636-9216-4787-86b5-cabc058bdb9b": {
                                "name": "Transformer 1.2.1",
                            },
                            "1e42137b-4ad0-4969-8d83-b27a16ccb5ff": {
                                "name": "Transformer 1.2.2",
                            }
                        },
}
```

Source object:

```
"4cab91b5-1732-40c3-81a7-6471da687061": {
                                "name": "Transformer 3.3.3",
                                
                            },
}
```

As you can notice the two keys are the same, I need to find the source's key into target and replace the data.

I tried various solutions about merging, cloning, etc. but none of them worked.